# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider - SQL Server CE - Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to connect a database with razor, to show the

```
data@ {
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutOuvinte.cshtml";

    var db = Database.Open("Entities");
    var selectQuery = "select * from musica";
    var grid = new WebGrid(db.Query(selectQuery));
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle:"table table-hover table-bordered",
headerStyle: null,
alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("au_Nome","Nome"),
    grid.Column("au_nomeArtista","NomeArtista")
    )
   ) 
</div>
```

But when I enter in view, this error is displayed:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

And this row the error appears:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(db.Query(selectQuery));
```

I take a look on google, but I don't find nothing to fix this bug using entity and SQL Server CE, this is my connection string in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144.mdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TccModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TccModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TccModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
    <add name="Entities"  
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144.mdf;initial catalog=aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: An `.mdf` file is a **full-blown** SQL Server database - **NOT** SQL Server CE! (that would be a `.sdf` file).

Comment: So, I need to change the file in web.config?

Comment: If you're really trying to use SQL Server **CE** - then yes, you need to change your connection strings.

Comment: @marc_s sorry by delay, I only want to use SQL Server, with "Entities" db